# Считывание данных с xml файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, beautiful-soup, bs4

Помогите пожалуйста с решением такой задачей:
Скрипт проходит по папкам и под папкам с помощью

```
os.walk()
```

находит папки где находятся два xml файла (1.xml, 2.xml) и сохраняет пути к ним в питоновский список, после чего парсит инфу с оба файла по путям из списка. В большинстве файлов 2.xml есть тэг

```xml
<Product Type="Voice">
```

но есть некоторые с тем же тэгом но на русском

```
<Продукт Тип="Голос">
```

Пытался решить данную задачу данным путем:

```py
file = open('путь к 2.xml', encoding='utf8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(file, 'html.parser')
try:
    file_type = soup.find('Product')['Type']
except:
    file_type = soup.find('Продукт')['Тип']
```

выдает ошибку:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Когда скрипт парсит файлы без
`<Продукт Тип="Голос">`, то есть только `<Product Type="Voice">`, то все нормально отрабатывает.

Спасибо заранее.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?> <Product Target_number="81234" Target="Q-3093-558877" Subcase_ID="4663" Subcase="6" Case_ID="1044" Case="GGG" Product_ID="5674856513" Type="Voice" ...>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?> <Продукт Номер_цели="80384" Цель="Q-2851-7899557774" ID_поддела="345" Поддело="435" ID_дела="234" Дело="6633" ID_продукта="123242345" Тип="Голос" ...>
```

Comment: Приведите в вопросе пример XML, с которой ошибка происходит

Comment: Разве с этой ошибка происходит? Вы ведь писали, что теги с кириллицей парсятся с ошибкой

Comment: Спасибо, но я просил в вопрос добавить, а не в комментарий :) Под вопросом есть кнопка `править`. Посмотрите мой ответ, это помогло вам?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вместо `html.parser` указывать `xml`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(file, 'xml')

try:
    file_type = soup.find('Product')['Type']
except:
    file_type = soup.find('Продукт')['Тип']

print(file_type)  # Голос
```

Файл:

```xml
<Продукты>
    <Продукт Тип="Голос"/>
    <Продукт Тип="Голос"/>
    <Продукт Тип="Голос"/>
    <Продукт Тип="Голос"/>
</Продукты>
```

---

**PS.**

Парсер `xml` это `lxml`, поэтому если его нет, нужно будет установить:

```
pip install lxml
```

**PPS.**

Парсер из стандартной библиотеки удачно нашел, можно им попробовать:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

file = open('путь к 2.xml', encoding='utf-8')
root = ET.parse(file)

file_type = root.find('Продукт').attrib['Тип']
print(file_type)  # Голос
```

Comment: проблема в том что я не знаю когда будет на кирилице а когда на латинице

Comment: @eeerrr, не вижу проблемы -- всегда используйте парсер `xml`. Или используйте парсер из коробки `xml.etree.ElementTree` -- код похожий, переписать не сложно будет.

Comment: написал 2 функции через:  одна отрабатывает кирилицу другая латиницу `try:
    file_type = ET.find('Product').attrib['Type']
except:
    file_type = ET.find('Продукт').attrib['Тип']
print(file_type)`   выскакивает ошибка `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrib'`

Comment: Извините за мою назойливость, подскажите как можно решить эту задачу. Спасибо.

Comment: @eeerrr, ничего страшного :) Как я писал выше, код оставляйте такой же (который ищет теги в двух вариантах: английском и русском), но вместо `html.parser` используйте `xml`. Парсер `xml` у меня удачно нашел теги на русском и английском, единственный минус, его нужно как устанавливать, например через команду `pip install lxml`. `BeautifulSoup` тоже нужно было устанавливать `pip install bs4`, поэтому не думаю что с lxml у вас будут проблемы. Кроме того, есть аналог `bs4`+`lxml`, который в PPS написал, но тот скорее всего потребует переписывания кода и разбирательства с ним

Comment: Та же ошибка - TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Код рабочий, а значит что-то упущено или неучтено. Запустите так, что у вас в коде было `soup = BeautifulSoup(file, 'xml')` и `file_type = soup.find('Продукт')['Тип']` `print(file_type)`. Убедитесь что у вас регистр тегов и атрибутов совпадает с тем, что в XML. Проверьте на опечатки. Если не получилось, выложите код и тестовую XML на https://gist.github.com/ и скиньте ссылку

Comment: Благодарю @gil9red , заработало на lxml. Думаю я где нибудь затупил, пытаясь переписав код используя поочередно библиотеки bs4, re и lxml.

Comment: @eeerrr, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)